# Removing Scotch tape residue

Tags: doors, paint, outdoor

Scotch tape and residue were gently scraped off the outdoor facing side of a wooden white door.  I would like to completely remove the residue.

Is there a clever method / tool / chemical to remove the residue without damaging the white paint?

Comment: Probably depends on the kind of white paint, what would work in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with WD-40 or similar product.  For really stubborn residue there is this stuff that often works where others don't:

[https://www.amazon.com/Original-Formula-Sticker-Remover-California/dp/B003TZQPTS/ref=asc_df_B003TZQPTS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003TZQPTS)

Comment: Sticker remover (not this particular brand) is my go to solvent for these kinds of residues, however I'm not sure if it'll discolour the white paint. I would test this on the side of the door first, somewhere less visible. And the trick is probably in applying it briefly in a rubbing motion, to maximise its effectiveness while minimising its contact with the paint.

Comment: @jwh20  Thanks for the reply.  Have you tried the AMZN product cited?

Comment: I have.  My wife uses it in her scrapbooking and I borrow it sometimes.  It sometimes works on those very stubborn residues.

Comment: Almost forgot, I use rubbing alcohol immediately afterward to remove any remaining sticker remover. This stuff can melt certain kinds of plastic (PP comes to mind), I'm sure extensive prolonged exposure would damage a fair number of materials.

Answer (score 1):

Goo-Gone or Goof-Off are popular choices but good ol' Windex works impressively well for sticker residue.

As always, test in an inconspicuous location first!!!

Also, you might find that the cleaned area is cleaner than then rest of the door.